# Using Regex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor

I'm trying to do this little something into one of my CKEditor plugins:

```
onOk:function(){
    var sInsert=this.getValueOf('info','insertcode_area');
    if ( sInsert.length > 0 ) {
    regex = new RegExp('(?<=\?v=)([-a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)', 'gi');

    url = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+sInsert.match(regex);
        sInsert = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="'+url+'" width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="'+url+'" /><a href="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash&#038;promoid=BIOW" target="blank"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get flash player to play to this file" width="88" height="31" /></a><br /></object>';

        e.insertHtml(sInsert);
  }
}
```

What it is supposed to do: Match the YouTube's video code into the entered URL and take it and concatenate to my url string so the URL is valid and embeddable.

But I currently get this error:

```
invalid quantifier ?<=?v=)([-a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

So I supposed it is a normal error and since I don't play with regex very often maybe I never saw this one :) So if someone could help me it would be great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally did it:

```
// First I replace those, so it'll become a valid YouTube embeddable URL.    
url = sInsert.replace('watch?v=', 'v/');
// Then I remove all the crap after the URL.
url = url.replace(url.substr(url.indexOf('&', 0), url.length), '');
```

Not a regex, but eh we do what we can do with what we have ;)

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 7):

You are using a 'positive lookbehind' `(?<=)` which is not supported by javascript

Comment: Yikes. And I thought nearly all flavors not supporting even basic advanced RE are long dead by now ...

Comment: @Tom: just use `/\?v=([-a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/i` without the lookbehind assertion.